# "Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource

Tags: spring-boot

spring-boot project running ok sometime have a probleam:

```
Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource 
[org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: 
Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate
```

Comment: Can you please post the whole stacktrace otherwise we cannot help you

Comment: one of the reason could be, unable to connect to DB.

Comment: find the log my server restart maybe this reason